# Change in thermohaline circulation due to climate change

Tags: climate-change, climate-models, ice, arctic, thermohaline-circulation

The melting of the North Polar ice masses removes a driving factor from the thermohaline circulation, known as the Gulf Stream in the North Atlantic. I wonder how much the thermohaline circulation has reduced in intensity over the last 60 years?

Comment: Interesting to note that Wikipedia/other spots [suggest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_Stream#:~:text=The%20Gulf%20Stream%20proper%20is,largely%20driven%20by%20thermohaline%20circulation) "the Gulf Stream proper is a western-intensified current, driven largely by wind stress", though it's also called part of the thermohaline circulation in many spots (very little oceanography background myself).  Would think any answer may involve that overlap to some degree?

Comment: Hi JeopardyTemoest, Yes I also found this, but I need this in a more detailed way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Climate models predict that under the influence of anthropogenic warming, the AMOC will decline during this century at a rate between 0 and 0.9 Sv per decade (1 Sv = 1 Mio. m3 s−1)                                                           For a warming of 1,5-2/2-3/3-5°C in 2100, the AMOC decline is 29/32/39% respectively to its pre-industrial strenght.

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41561-021-00699-z/figures/1                https://climatetippingpoints.files.wordpress.com/2021/09/image-9.png    https://climatetippingpoints.files.wordpress.com/2021/08/image-4.png

Comment: I was initially confused by the unit Sv, as this is an SI unit for ionizing radiation [Sievert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert). I see oceanographers use Sv as an abbreviation for the non SI unit [Sverdrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sverdrup).